# Hushed Whispers not a choice

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I went to Val Royeaux and talked to Fiona. But when I went to the war council all I see as an option is Champions of the Just. I didn't say anything about talking to one over the other, is it is glitch? And if so, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/In_Hushed_Whispers says that "Unlike Champions of the Just, the Inquisition must meet the mages in Redcliffe before the operation becomes available on the war table. ". Did you do that?

Comment: I did not. So go to Redcliffe?

Comment: I didn't see any quest saying to do that.

Comment: I haven't played Inquisition in a while, but yeah, I would try that. Follow the link in my first comment, there's a lot of information there.

Comment: I will check it out. Make an answer and I will upvote, accept if it pans out.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to bother with this one. I have enough rep from well-formatted wikia summaries. Anyone's welcome to steal the link and write an answer, including you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DCShannon said "dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/In_Hushed_Whispers says that "Unlike Champions of the Just, the Inquisition must meet the mages in Redcliffe before the operation becomes available on the war table."

I did this and it worked for me.